# Inferring generics from parent class in method signature fails

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I'm using a library with (hundreds of, template-generated) classes without generic modifier, each extending the same classes with generic modifier (essentially to shorten the notation). E.g.

```
class DArr : NumberObject<double, MyArrayIndexer> { ... }
class IArr : NumberObject<int, MyArrayIndexer> { ... }
class DMat : NumberObject<double, MyMatrixIndexer> { ... }
class IMat : NumberObject<int, MyMatrixIndexer> { ... }
class BMat : NumberObject<bool, MyMatrixIndexer> { ... }
and so on
```

I now want to write functions that proccess these with a function that requires their internal type (e.g. internal copies that need to know whether we have 4 or 8 bytes per element, and what type of Indexer is being used). I therefore made the signature of my function:

```
public SomeUnrelatedClass<T> Process<T,TVal,T0>(SomeUnrelatedClass<T> obj) where T : NumberObject<TVal,T0> {
 //here some tstuff that requires T, TVal and T0
}
```

but unfortunately it seems I can't use it in the way I need to, i.e.

```
SomeUnrelatedClass<DArr> input = ...;
SomeUnrelatedClass<DArr> output = Process(input);
```

since it fails to derive TVal and T0 from (why??), despite it being uniquely determined. How can I remedy this? Calling it as `SomeUnrelatedClass<DArr> output = Process<DArr,double,MyArrayIndexer>(input);` is not an option because in reality there's a lot more of these generics and they're a lot longer in name (and this function will be used thousands of times in future code, so I'd much rather now write a more complicated function that does it right and keeps the syntax simple). Ideally I'd not do a long list of "if type == ..." though, because the list of types is template-generated and changes over time as types get added (meaning this template would be dependent on the other template, etc.)

I've thought of silly hacks like making the syntax `Process<T,TVal,T0>(SomeUnrelatedClass<T> obj,SomeUnrelatedClass<NumberObject<TVal,T0>> sameObj)` and calling `SomeUnrelatedClass<DArr> output = Process(input,input);` but I feel like that's just a really poor fix. What's a more 'proper' way to do this?

Comment: I know languages that support this, but C# is not one of them. You would have to think of work arounds.

Comment: You want to get the string of ```double``` ```MyArrayIndexer``` for ```class DArr : NumberObject<double, MyArrayIndexer> ```?

Comment: I've added a comment to ahybertz answer that give you exactly what you want. Try this signature: `public static SomeUnrelatedClass<T> Process<T, TVal, T0>(T input) where T : NumberObject<TVal, T0>`.

Comment: Can you move the `Process` method into the `SomeUnrelatedClass` class? Because it obviously knows what all the types are.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be in some luck here, because C# does not infer types based on the constraints that you specify. I think it's part of the specification, from what I could dig out. But you might be able to solve you problem anyway :) - I managed to get the following running.

```
{
    var input = new DArr(12.34);
    var output = Visitor.Process(input);
    Console.WriteLine($"Type [{output.Obj.GetType()}] with value {output.Obj.MyType}");
}
{
    var input = new IArr(42);
    var output = Visitor.Process(input);
    Console.WriteLine($"Type [{output.Obj.GetType()}] with value {output.Obj.MyType}");
}

// Generated output:
//
// Type [DArr] with value 12,34
// Type [IArr] with value 42
```

So no matter how many types you define that **Process** method will consume and map the input to the right concrete type.

Below is how this could work:

```
public class NumberObject<TType, TIndexer>
{
    public NumberObject(TType type) { MyType = type; }
    public TType MyType { get; }
}

public class MyArrayIndexer { }

public class DArr : NumberObject<double, MyArrayIndexer>
{
    public DArr(double value) : base(value) { }
}

public class IArr : NumberObject<int, MyArrayIndexer>
{
    public IArr(int value) : base(value) { }
}

public class SomeUnrelatedClass<T>
{
    public T Obj { get; }

    public SomeUnrelatedClass(T obj){ Obj = obj; }
}

public class Visitor
{
    public static SomeUnrelatedClass<NumberObject<TVal, T0>> Process<TVal, T0>(NumberObject<TVal, T0> input)
    {
        return new SomeUnrelatedClass<NumberObject<TVal, T0>>(input);
    }
}
```

The trick here is to reduce the number of generic parameters - getting rid of the **T** type as it can directly be expressed by the remaining two as you actually also write yourself

```
T is NumberObject<TVal, T0>
```

When the level of types to infer is reduced the C# compiler can determine them directly and viola you can leave you specifying generic parameters to the **Process** method.

Comment: But this will return a `SomeUnrelatedClass<NumberObject<TVal,T0>> out`, not a `SomeUnrelatedClass<T>`, no?

Comment: No it will return the original type - like I show with the GetType() call above in the generated output

Comment: How would one use that then? When I copy paste your code and do `SomeUnrelatedClass<DArr> x = null; var y = Visitor.Process(x);` it complains that the type of TVal and T0 cannot be derived.

Comment: You use it as in the example - have a look at how the **SomeUnrelatedClass<T>** is implemented. It stores the original type as a property *Obj* and you have access to it that way. My suggestion assumes that you have access to **SomeUnrelatedClass** and can make the needed changes.

Comment: Do you need to be able to pass *null* to the **Process** method?

Comment: Depending on your use-case you can also return a *dynamic* from the **Process** method - something like 

`public static dynamic ProcessDynamic<TVal, T0>(NumberObject<TVal, T0> input)
    {
        var result = new SomeUnrelatedClass<NumberObject<TVal, T0>>(input);

        return result.Obj;
    }`

But *dynamic* should be used only when absolutely needed and the cost should be fully understood.

Comment: Your example processes a `DArr` to a `DArr`, not a `SomeUnrelatedClass<DArr>` to a `SomeUnrelatedClass<DArr>`? When I adjust the code in the way that seems most plausible, `output` seems to be of type `SomeUnrelatedClass<NumberObject<double, MyArrayIndexer>>`, not `SomeUnrelatedClass<DArr>`, so I'm not sure that I understand how to correctly use your example. (And I had indeed not yet considered `dynamic`, I'll read more into that meanwhile, thanks for the pointer!)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226667/discussion-between-ahybertz-and-peter).

Comment: @ahybertz - If you change the signature of `Process` to `public static SomeUnrelatedClass<T> Process<T, TVal, T0>(T input) where T : NumberObject<TVal, T0>` then you can give the OP exactly what they wanted.

Comment: @Enigmativity Isn't that exactly the statement used in my question, of which I'm asking a workaround because it's not able to determine the types TVal and T0 from that?

Comment: @Peter - Sorry, I didn't see that when I read your question. Odd, the code worked for me.